# How does one load a URL from a .NET client application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, client

What is the preferred way to open a URL from a thick client application on Windows using C# and the .NET framework?  I want it to use the default browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code surely works:

```
Process.Start("http://www.yoururl.com/Blah.aspx");
```

It opens the default browser (technically, the default program that handles HTTP URIs).

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the [Process.Start method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_).

Answer (score 1):

```
private void launchURL_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){
 string targetURL = "http://stackoverflow.com";
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(targetURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```